# OPENXML. How to apply multiple paragraph properties in a single run

Tags: c#, openxml

Is there any way to create the Paragraph , run it and apply multiple properties in a single statemement instead of creating 'RunProperties' and append the the styles on by one.
In the example I am trying to add a second style - Font size like that but it doesn't work.

```
TableCell tc1_1 = new TableCell();

tc1_1.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "5500" }));

tc1_1.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(

    new Text("Test Company Name 123123123 123123"),

    new FontSize() { Val = "8" }

)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating invalid Open XML markup. For example, if you want to specify the font size for a specific run, this needs to be done by adding the `FontSize` instance to a  `RunProperties` instance (i.e., `w:rPr` element).

My general recommendation is to look at Open XML markup created by Microsoft Word for what you want to have in your document, e.g., a table cell with some paragraphs and runs formatted in a certain way. You can then mimic in your code what Word has created.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point me to the right web source, I was looking for it but I couldn't find it.

Comment: One source is [Datypic](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/). Another one is [C-REX](https://c-rex.net/projects/samples/ooxml/e1/index.html). Further, please accept my answer and upvote if it helped you.